# Xcode 7 beta Code Signing Watch OS 2

Tags: watchkit, code-signing, provisioning-profile, watchos-2, xcode7-beta5

I've added a new Watch OS 2 target to my build. The project works fine and compiles when testing on my Apple Watch. However, when I try to archive the project for distribution, I get a code signing error about the provisioning profile not being available for the Watch OS 2 extension. In the code signing section of the watch extension, there is no provisioning profile line. I'm assuming this is because iOS 9 / Watch OS 2 App Store submissions are not yet open. Is it possible to add the provisioning profile line manually? Please see attached screenshots.

[image: Watch OS 2 Code Signing]

[image: Main iOS App Code Signing]